# What GC will clear first? means local variables or objects or..need order of execution

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help to answer order / priority of GC execution. If local variables / objects are available GC then which will execute first?

Comment: Not only does the GC algorithm vary by Android OS version, I do not think it is safe for you to be making any assumptions about the order in which objects get garbage collected.

Comment: Actually this question was asked at one of the interview. Is Garbage Collector code is available ? Where we can see   androidxref it's there?

Comment: "this question was asked at one of the interview" -- whoever asked the question is very scary. "Where we can see androidxref it's there?" -- I have no idea off the top of my head. But, again, the rules of GC vary by Android version.

Comment: Local variables do not need to be GC'd anyway -- they live on the stack, not the heap.  Objects *referenced by* local variables of reference type may be a different matter, however.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are not subject to GC, they are allocated on the stack. If objects belong to those variables, those are of course subject to GC.

I think beyond that, the only reliable things that can be said is the concept of a generational GC ([Java documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)). The details differ between versions, but in general most garbage collections are "minor" garbage collections, where only recently generated objects are cleaned up. Objects that have survived a few GC rounds get moved to a lower priority space that gets garbage collected less often (the number of levels changes depending on the Android version, as does the treatment of huge objects).